# Backstage running on aws fargate can't fetch catalog on private gitlab repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, aws-fargate, backstage

I'm trying to run [backstage](https://backstage.io/) on AWS Fargate, but I'm facing a problem fetching the service catalog that is hosted on a private gitlab.

Both gitlab and backstage are running on the same vpc and same private subnets.

When I run backstage both locally with `yarn dev` and docker, backstage can fetch the catalog with no problem. But when I run a task in Fargate, he can't fetch it.

The error presented on backstage is:

[image]

When I call the entites api on `/api/catalog/entities`, the return is:

```
"status": {
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "backstage.io/catalog-processing",
            "level": "error",
            "message": "Error: Unable to read url, Error: Could not get GitLab project ID for: https://gitlab.srv-cld.xxx.com.br/x/x/backstage-architecture/-/blob/master/systems/user/services/document-service/api.yaml, Error: GitLab Error 'undefined', undefined",
            "error": {
                "name": "Error",
                "message": "Unable to read url, Error: Could not get GitLab project ID for: https://gitlab.srv-cld.xxx.com.br/x/x/backstage-architecture/-/blob/master/systems/user/services/document-service/api.yaml, Error: GitLab Error 'undefined', undefined"
            }
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

The catalog on app-config.yml is:

```
catalog:
  import:
    entityFilename: catalog-info.yaml
    pullRequestBranchName: backstage-integration
  rules:
    - allow: [Component, System, API, Resource, Location]
  locations:
    - type: url
      target: https://gitlab.aaa.bbb.com.br/arquitetura/exemplos/backstage-architecture/-/blob/master/architecture.yaml
```

And the integrations is:

```
integrations:
  gitlab:
    - host: gitlab.aaa.bbb.com.br
      apiBaseUrl: https://gitlab.aaa.bbb.com.br/api/v4
      token: ${GITLAB_TOKEN}
```

I really can't understand why backstage can't get the project id when running on fargate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close the question, it was not a problem with backstage or self hosted gitlab. It was a problem mapping the env `GITLAB_TOKEN` in the task definition.